# How to Check if an Array of Records Contain EVERY string in another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an array of records resulting from a `WHERE` active record query. Each record has two to sixteen strings as its properties. I need to see if any record contains all of the strings in another array as its properties. How can I achieve this?

**Sample Array of Strings:**

```
["12349", "12IUS823", "4809JDSL"]
```

**Sample Record in an Array of Similar Records**

**Product**

- id1
- id2
- id3
- id4
- id5
- id6

Comment: can you more clearly specify the array of products . just saying id1 , id2 doesnt clarify on how the array of products will actually look like . And also to which product field do we need to check the other array with ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can get an array of all the string properties via `strings` method. I would check if the difference of arrays is empty. It selects records that have at least all the strings in `arr`

```
arr = ["12349", "12IUS823", "4809JDSL"]

records.select{|x| (arr - x.strings ).empty? }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this...

`["12349", "12IUS823", "4809JDSL"].all? { |value| [ id1 , id2 , id3 ].any? { |id| id == value } }`